# Meteor error with './browsers' module

Tags: node.js, meteor

I started working with meteor and reaction recently, but when I try running `meteor run` I get the following error:

```
W20161028-00:06:04.629(-6)? (STDERR) /home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.ihe772++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20161028-00:06:04.630(-6)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20161028-00:06:04.631(-6)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20161028-00:06:04.631(-6)? (STDERR) 
W20161028-00:06:04.632(-6)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module './browsers'
W20161028-00:06:04.632(-6)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:109:19)
W20161028-00:06:04.633(-6)? (STDERR)     at packages/modules.js:2899:14
W20161028-00:06:04.633(-6)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.autoprefixer.lib.autoprefixer.js (packages/modules.js:2978:4)
W20161028-00:06:04.633(-6)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
W20161028-00:06:04.633(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:106:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.634(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.import (/home/user/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.7.1gylz5r++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.634(-6)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.api.core.ui.js (server/api/core/ui.js:1:1)
W20161028-00:06:04.634(-6)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
W20161028-00:06:04.635(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:106:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.635(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.import (/home/user/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.7.1gylz5r++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.635(-6)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.api.core.index.js (server/api/core/index.js:1:1)
W20161028-00:06:04.635(-6)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
W20161028-00:06:04.635(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:106:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.636(-6)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.import (/home/user/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.7.1gylz5r++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
W20161028-00:06:04.636(-6)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.api.index.js (server/api/index.js:1:1)
W20161028-00:06:04.636(-6)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:181:9)
```

I'm working on a linux machine using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 x86

I even tried running `npm install --save fibers` thinking it might be something with that package but still doesn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of meteor are you on?

Comment: @blueren I'm using v1.4.2 (latest, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: it could be some package that you're using. Can you selectively remove certain packages to see if the same is happening?

Comment: @blueren yes, I think I can do that. Which packages should I remove? Fibers?

Comment: I'm really not sure at this point. Was there a time till which things were working fine, and then you installed a few packages, and then it went bonkers? I've noticed, that usually it's a rogue package. Either that or the load order

Comment: @blueren Actually this is the first time I'm trying to run this app, after I went ahead and installed what's required it started throwing the error. And unfortunately haven't been able to run it.